# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable. sum() function

Tags: python-3.x

Can anyone explain why jupyter notebook says: "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable", When trying to execute the following code:

```
a = [3, 2, 6, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 0, 3, 6, 7, 4, 6, 3]
b = sum(a)
print(b)
```

But PyCharm returns: 53

????

Comment: You probably defined `sum` as a list earlier in your code in the Jupyter notebook. To override that, just run `del sum` in a cell, which will delete the variable, but not the built-in function.

Comment: do not ever use names of built ins as variable names - they shadow the built in function - in your case: `sum()`. Use `print(type(sum))` to check - if it is anything other then a function you used it as variable somewhere

Comment: Thats it yes, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jupyter notebook allows you to run code line by line, which means that if you defined a variable called "sum" in one of the cells, and this variable has a list in it, the "sum" function is overwritten until you restart the kernel, and know only the variable exists, which cannot be called.